# flutter navigate to new page in my android from flutter view

Tags: android, flutter

I have added flutter to my android app using [this example](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Add-Flutter-to-existing-apps).
my flutter view is shown okay,however now i want to close the view from flutter and return to my android code is there any other way other than starting a platform channel,to close the current view.

Comment: I think you can get help faster if you are a bit more clear about what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

I had opened such an issues in flutter GitHub repository.
[here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/25235)